# How to calculate the complexity of C# code?

Tags: c#-4.0

How do i know that what is the complexity of my C# pragram

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace basic
{
class Hello
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
    }
}
}
```

I want to know that what is the complexity of the above given code

Comment: According to what complexity measure?

Answer (score 1):

There are several different kinds of measures of software complexity. A common one is Cyclomatic complexity. It roughly measures the number of branching statments in a codebase. Since your sample code has no ifs or for-loops the cyclomatic complexity would be 1.

There are [other measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_complexity) which you could use to calculate some complexity aspect of the codebase. And there are tools like [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) which can be used to calculate a number of measures in a C# codebase.

Comment: thanxxx..
actually i am thinking in this way that suppose i am writting a code for a particular problem in two diffrent way then how do i know that which way is more efficient n less complex

Comment: The efficiency of your code can be tested through performance tests, e.g. running the same code several times with a few different inputs. You could also do some form of order of growth analysis to see how your algorithm will perform given larger and larger inputs. As for complexity, you could use cyclomatic complexity, count the number of dependencies or some other measure.